# Best way to include interactive external content in a page (JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface

I'm going to be creating a widget style tool that will work as follows:

1. It can be included in any page by putting a script/button combo on that page.
2. The button, when clicked, will load a form from my site, which can be filled out and submitted.
3. Depending on the submitted information, there may be another form displayed - for example, a second page with a captcha, or a confirmation page with some action required, or maybe just have the form close, or some other action I add later.

If I was to open a popup window, this would be easy, just build it as a regular page.  However, including this in a calling page, presents a few issues.

If I actually load the form content into a local div on the calling page, it becomes part of the page content.  I know I can manipulate that content to some extent using the script (it will load a script from my site for that particular version of the widget), repost forms and load them into the same div, hide the div when I'm done with it, etc.  But it seems like it would complicate things.

My other option is to make it all happen in an iframe, so it's not really part of the loading page calling page.  This way I sort of feel like I'm losing some functionality I may need later.  This is probably the way I will go anyway.

However, before I start down that road, I thought I would ask if anyone has any tips on the best way to include a complex series of pages in another page?

Whatever I do, I want to be sure I don't close doors on my ability to change the way the widget functions, I will definitely be adding functionality later - so keeping my options open for change is important.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Regarding JotaBe's question, on the server side, I will be using PHP.

However, I'm pretty sure that doesn't matter, as the PHP processing will (as always) happen on the server.  All the client (requesting page), will know is that it requested, and then received JS/HTML/CSS/JSON/ETC assets via HTTP.  It won't know, or care, how the server generated those resources.

If it helps you to picture it though, this is the basic idea of how the client and server will (if I don't think of a better way) work together:

1. The client page will (at load) request a .js file from my site.  This file will be generated dynamically based on the requested URL.  For example, account #74 would request **http://mysite.com/widget/js/74.js** and receive JavaScript assets customized for that account.
2. When the "widget button" is clicked, it will use the JavaScript to request an HTML form from my site, and include it in the page, one way or another (which way is best is the whole question).  The HTML form will be generated dynamically and customized for account # 74 based on the request (ie: **http://mysite.com/widget/form/74.php**).
3. Once filled by the user, the form will be submitted to my site.  The post will be processed and **stuff** will happen, again based on the requesting account (ie: **action=http://mysite.com/widget/post/74.php**).  At this point, I may need to reject the form and request a re-post for failed validation, captcha verification, etc., or I may need to serve a confirmation page, or simply close the form, or some other action.

Comment: What's on the server side? If you use ASP.NET MVC you can do that by using user controls, and showing them using AJAX. Your problem is not simply on the client side, and we can't help you if you don't tell what's on the server side.

Comment: I would go iframe, unless your up for using AJAX to pull the content and display it on the same page. This seems like exactly the sort of thing that the iframe is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Any way you do this (language / platform / etc), the best practice is to use mvc, or hmvc, to keep the various logical components of the application separate.  You can create popups by having some view templates which don't render their containing  tags, designed for javascript / jquery .load() statements.  You could then design a series of components designed to be loaded with arguments passed over the uri.

here is an article that might help explain one possible design pattern for what you are going for:
http://www.phpied.com/ajax-mvc/